# Set the time or clock value in an SVG animation?

Tags: animation, svg

I have created an animated SVG that cycles repeatedly. Can I set the time so that when the document is first loaded, it is 50% through the animation and proceeds from there?

I use POV-Ray sometimes and I know that you can set the current clock value to between 0.0 and 1.0 in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are working with SMIL animation on an HTML page, I would let the animation start at minus half of the duration, e.g.

```
<animate ... dur="10s" begin="-5s" repeatCount="indefinite" ...>
```

The animation starts immediately, but in the middle of the "previous" cycle.

I am not aware of a clock value like in POVRay to jump to a certain time within an animation.

I hope this still helps, almost one year after the question had been posted.